# How to set up a PostgreSQL database in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2, django-settings

I'm new to Python and Django.

I'm configuring a Django project using a PostgreSQL database engine backend, But I'm getting errors on each database operation. For example when I run `manage.py syncdb`, I'm getting:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\djangodir>python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
67, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in im
port_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py"
, line 7, in <module>
    from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_
signal
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py", line 6, in
 <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 77, in <modul
e>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 92, in __getitem
__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 33, in load_back
end
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in im
port_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", li
ne 23, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg module: No mo
dule named psycopg
```

Can someone give me a clue on what is going on?

Comment: Seems quite clear: there's no module named psycopg. Have you installed it?

Comment: No, I haven't. I will try to do it

Comment: can someone tell why do we need psycopg2 with django?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

You need to install [`psycopg2`](http://initd.org/psycopg/) Python library.

### Installation

---

Download http://initd.org/psycopg/, then install it under Python PATH

After downloading, easily extract the tarball and:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

Or if you wish, install it by either [easy_install](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) or [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/).

<sup>(*I prefer to use pip over easy_install for no reason.*)</sup>

- `$ easy_install psycopg2`
- `$ pip install psycopg2`

### Configuration

---

in **settings**.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',                      
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_user_password',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': 'db_port_number',
    }
}
```

---

<sup>- Other installation instructions can be found at [download page](http://initd.org/psycopg/download/) and [install page](http://initd.org/psycopg/install/).</sup>

Comment: Hi, I follow your instruction but it seems I should create the user/pwd pair before I use them in the settings.py?

Comment: @Yulong you have to create an `user` for postgres, but password is not necessary.

Comment: but I get this `psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied` when I run `python manage.py syncdb`. I set random table name and user name.

Comment: @Yulong I have never exprience such an error about it, but maybe this help you. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-users/Sx3WLelcyEg  Let me know if it solved the issue.

Comment: I will try it. for now since i am trying a heroku deployment I will first find if there is a heroku-compatible way. but still thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Is it Python 3.3 compatible?

Comment: If you want to use it with Django, No it's not. Django itself is not compatible with python3 yet, I think psycopg2 is compatible with python3, You have to compile it yourself. Look at this comment: http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2012/03/29/psycopg-245-released/#c92

Comment: make sure you have `python-dev` installed for `psycopg2`. Might be obvious to most people but it tripped me up on a recent server config.

Comment: All psycopg2 links are dead

Comment: what is "django & python PATH"?

Comment: FYI: As of Django 1.9 you can say: 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',

Comment: @powlo Thanks for the comment, I have updated the post regarding to it.

Comment: In Mojave (OS X 10.14) `pip install psycopg2` did not initially work for me (python 3.7, django 2.2). See detailed solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57014480/2162844

Comment: The problem that I had with this answer is that `django.db.backends.postgresql` dosn't work with `psycopg2`. what worked is `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2` back end and avoided specifying port number as it change every time you start pgAdmin on windows

Answer (score 31):

Also make sure you have the PostgreSQL development package installed.
On Ubuntu you need to do something like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Answer (score 27):

Step by step that I use:

```
 - sudo apt-get install python-dev
 - sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.1
 - sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2 - Or sudo pip install psycopg2
```

You may want to install a graphic tool to manage your databases, for that you can do:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql pgadmin4
```

After, you must change Postgre user password, then do:

```
 - sudo su
 - su postgres -c psql postgres
 - ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'YourPassWordHere';
 - \q
```

On your settings.py file you do:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Extra:

If you want to create the db using the command line you can just do:

```
- sudo su
- su postgres -c psql postgres
- CREATE DATABASE dbname;
- CREATE USER djangouser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'myPasswordHere';
- GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE dbname TO djangouser;
```

On your settings.py file you do:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'djangouser',
        'PASSWORD': 'myPasswordHere',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can  install "psycopg" with the following command:

```
# sudo easy_install psycopg2
```

Alternatively, you can use pip :

```
# pip install psycopg2
```

easy_install and pip are included with [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads), or manually installed from the [respective](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/#installation-instructions) [project](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) sites.

Or, simply get the [pre-built Windows installer](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/).

Comment: Or `sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2` if you are on a Debian system and want to use the package manager rather than pip/easy_install.

Answer (score 6):

This may seem a bit lengthy, but it worked for me without any error.

At first, Install phppgadmin from Ubuntu Software Center.

Then run these steps in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
pip install psycopg2
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib phppgadmin
```

Start the apache server

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

Now run this too in terminal, to edit the apache file.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Add the following line to the opened file:

```
Include /etc/apache2/conf.d/phppgadmin
```

Now reload apache. Use terminal.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Now you will have to create a new database. Login as 'postgres' user. Continue in terminal.

```
sudo su - postgres
```

In case you have trouble with the password of 'postgres', you can change it using the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12721020/1990793 and continue with the steps.

Now create a database

```
createdb <db_name>
```

Now create a new user to login to phppgadmin later, providing a new password.

```
createuser -P <new_user>
```

Now your postgressql has been setup, and you can go to:

```
http://localhost/phppgadmin/
```

and login using the new user you've created, in order to view the database.

Comment: why bother with php? The question is about Django ...?

Comment: @SidhinThomas phpPgAdmin is a common administration tool for PostgreSQL. It does not depend on what language/framework the database runs on.

Comment: isn't there anything like MySQL workbench for Postgres?

Comment: @SidhinThomas Yes there are a lot of GUI tools similar to MySQL workbench. Take a look here. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Answer (score 5):

The immediate problem seems to be that you're missing the [psycopg2](http://www.initd.org/psycopg/) module.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Fedora 20, Django 1.6.5, postgresql 9.3.* and you need the psycopg2 module, do this:

```
yum install postgresql-devel
easy_install psycopg2
```

If you are like me, you may have trouble finding the well documented libpq-dev rpm... The above worked for me just now.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same Issue on **Mac**.

The solution was to use only **PIP** to install everything, and touch some things.

**First install PIP from:** https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/

Then you want to make sure if path to **pg_config** is in your **PATH** (echo $PATH), if not you can edit your bash_profile:

```
vi /Users/<user>/.bash_profile
```

and add this line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/pg_config/bin
```

If you don't know where pg_config is you can use the "locate" tool, but be sure your locate.db is up to date (i was using an old locate.db and using paths that does not exists).

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
locate pg_config
```

Then install Django (if needed) and psycopg2.

```
sudo pip install Django
sudo pip install psycopg2
```

And then in settings.py (localhost:defaultport)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Greets!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Year, this solve my problem.
After execute this, do:
pip install psycopg2

Answer (score 1):

Steps to create a Django app with PostgreSQL database from scratch.

1. Check if PostgreSQL is installed in your system. In your bash shell enter

   ```
   psql --version
   ```
2. If PostgreSQL is installed jump to step 6.
3. To install PostgreSQL -

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python3-dev libpq-dev

   sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
   ```
4. By default PostgreSQL installation creates a special user named "postgres" that has all rights. To login to PostgreSQL

   ```
   sudo -u postgres psql
   ```

   To exit PostgreSQL session

   ```
   \q
   ```
5. Now set password for "postgres" user.

   Login to PostgreSQL -

   ```
   sudo -u postgres psql
   ```

   In PostgreSQL interactive session enter -

   ```
   \password postgres
   ```
6. Create PostgreSQL database.

   To create directly from bash shell -

   ```
   sudo -u postgres createdb your_db_name
   ```

   To create from PostgreSQL interactive session -

   ```
   createdb your_db_name
   ```

   To check if the database is created, list all databases using PostgreSQL command

   ```
   \l
   ```
7. If you already have an existing Django project then jump to step 11. Otherwise create a virtual environment. I use virtualenv wrapper.

   ```
   mkvirtualenv your_project_name
   ```
8. Create Django project.

   ```
   django-admin startproject your_project_name
   ```
9. Cd to the project directory and create your app.

   ```
    python manage.py startapp your_app_name
   ```
10. Install Django.

    ```
    pip install django
    ```
11. Install Psycopg2. Psycopg2 is a PostgreSQL database adapter for Python. This is required for Django to connect with PostgreSQL.

    ```
    pip install psycopg2
    ```
12. Update settings.py as follows

    ```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'your_db_name',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '',
        }
    }
    ```
13. Run migration.

    ```
    python3 manage.py migrate
    ```
14. Run Django server and visit localhost:8000

    ```
    python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ```
15. If required you can install pgadmin - a graphical client to view and manipulate PostgreSQL database schema and data.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that installation of `psycopg2` via pip or setup.py requires to have Visual Studio  2008 (more precisely executable file *vcvarsall.bat*). If you don't have admin rights to install it or set the appropriate PATH variable on Windows, you can download already compiled library from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg).

Comment: What about this?  Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7  ==>> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the very good and step by step process to set up `PostgreSQL` in ubuntu server. I have tried it with `Ubuntu 16.04` and its working.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score -2):

postgres runs on port 5432

specify this in settings.py

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-postgres.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).