# How can I change a PostgreSQL user password?

Tags: postgresql, change-password

How do I change the password for a PostgreSQL user?

Comment: Confusingly, the (literal) name of the *default user* is ***"postgres"***. *[What is the default username and password for PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118759/)*.

Comment: And *"[Is "postgres" a default and special user of PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50883645/)"*

Comment: It's worth noting that "postgres" is the default *registered* user.  The default user used when running `psql` is the current shell user (`echo $USER`). To login to `psql` as "postgres" when the current shell user is not "postgres", we need to run `psql` as  "postgres" with `sudo -u postgres psql`. Also, note that we can't switch the current shell user to "postgres" since [that account is locked by default](https://serverfault.com/a/325596/593435).

Answer (score 2532, accepted):

To log in without a password:

```
sudo -u user_name psql db_name
```

To reset the password if you have forgotten:

```
ALTER USER user_name WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';
```

Comment: This let the clear password in the user's postgresql command history.

Comment: @greg: so delete it: `rm ~/.psql_history`

Comment: off topic but if anyone looking for "how to change name of user" than do `ALTER USER myuser RENAME TO newname;` ...for some reason google was pointing me here when I was googling that :)

Comment: @RickyA Don't forget to clear the db logs too, those might contain plaintext passwords as well.

Comment: Why are you using both " and ' quotes? I mean, there's a difference, and in a DML query you have to use ' when dealing with strings, but is there a special reason to use both of them here?

Comment: Using single quote ' for the role name doesn't work, but I am still curious why?

Comment: The user is an object, not a string.  Compare with ALTER TABLE "table_name" or even SELECT * FROM "table_name".  You couldn't use single quotes in these contexts with tables, and it's the same with users/roles.

Comment: @RickyA deleting the file doesn't mean that the password would be deleted on the system tough, it could be found through forensics with stuff like photorec, so you would need to `shred` it, etc...

Comment: @DragonRock won't help you on SSDs either or even probably newer versions of ext in general.

Comment: @dualed yeah, you're right. Getting totally rid of a file is kind of complicated. It's way better to never have it saved in the first place !

Comment: Just curious but why is an (now unused) password a problem in the log files? It got changed and thus is useless or am I wrong?

Comment: what does the first line do?

Comment: @greg @RickyA instead of deleting the whole `.psql_history` it is sufficient to issue the command with some whitespace before `ALTER USER`, and it will not be stored in `.psql_history`. This same handy trick is available in standard shell as well.

Comment: please use `ENCRYPTED PASSWORD`

Comment: @Alphaaa I think that only works if you have `\set HISTCONTROL ignorespace` set in the .psqlrc file.

Comment: Yes @GregoryArenius, your .psqlrc file should contain `\set HISTCONTROL ignorespace` or `\set HISTCONTROL ignoreboth` for my suggestion to work.

Comment: @Natim From the docs: `The password is always stored encrypted in the system catalogs. The ENCRYPTED keyword has no effect, but is accepted for backwards compatibility.` But you can send an encrypted password: `If the presented password string is already in MD5-encrypted or SCRAM-encrypted format, then it is stored as-is regardless of password_encryption.` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html

Comment: If you use the `\password` command in `psql` then the history will not contain the password. (At least in Version 9.2.24)

Comment: ### Use DOUBLE QUOTE for the user if it contains a period.

Comment: the **unencrypted password  is rememberd by `psql` history** or shell... Same for SQL command `ENCRYPTED PASSWORD` (!). **How to use encrypted/hashed (ex. SHA256) password?**

Comment: This way (without quotes around the user name) will only work for certain user names.

Comment: -bash: -u: command not found

Answer (score 1268):

To change the PostgreSQL user's password, follow these steps:

1. log in into the psql console:

   ```
   sudo -u postgres psql
   ```
2. Then in the *psql* console, change the password and quit:

   ```
   postgres=# \password postgres
   Enter new password: <new-password>
   postgres=# \q
   ```

Or using a query:

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD '<new-password>';
```

Or in one line

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD '<new-password>';"
```

##### Note:

If that does not work, reconfigure authentication by editing `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf` (the path will differ) and change:

```
local     all         all             peer # change this to md5
```

to

```
local     all         all             md5 # like this
```

Then restart the server:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Comment: whats the default password for postgres? changed it accidently; possible to reset?

Comment: (on psql 9.2) if I type in `\p`, it gives me the password; if I type in `\password postgres` it gives the password and then warnings `\p extra argument "assword" ignored; \p extra argument "postgres" ignored`

Comment: If you have made the change using \password and you are on the same host as the postgres server, the try specifying that you want your connection to go over an inet instead of unix socket. i.e. use the -h parameter: psql -h 127.0.0.1. Doing this saved me from editing the pg_hba configuration file

Comment: If only for my reference, `local all postgres md5` allows local logins for postgres with interactive password entry but better yet is existing `host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5` allows `sudo psql --host 127.0.0.1 --username postgres --password` to log in interactively for postgres login without pg_hba.conf changes.

Comment: This is much better than leaving the password in SQL command history.

Comment: @ZacharyScott What are you saying?

Comment: To change the password on the postgres user in Linux: `sudo passwd postgres`

Comment: If you want to change the password for someone other then `postgres` user, the `\password` command accepts the role name as the 1st argument: `\password <role_name>` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-alterrole.html

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks a lot, I see I've upvoted it long time ago, so glad I found it *again*!

Comment: @Punnerud, _"To change the password on the postgres user in Linux: `sudo passwd postgres`"_ Holy Smokes! I was so confoosed. Both Postgres and Linux have the same user. I'm new to postgres and using it with a new Django site. I needed a backup of the DB and picking 5 random tutorials, this was not explained well. LSS this solved the password problem so I could make a backup.

Comment: I connected using the account I want to change the password for, and then ran `\password` without anything after. I could change the password successfully and securely. Good answer.

Comment: Use only ' (single quote)

Answer (score 147):

I believe the best way to change the password is simply to use:

```
\password
```

in the Postgres console.

Per `ALTER USER` [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-alterrole.html):

> Caution must be exercised when specifying an unencrypted password with
> this command. The password will be transmitted to the server in
> cleartext, and it might also be logged in the client's command history
> or the server log. psql contains a command \password that can be used
> to change a role's password without exposing the cleartext password.

Note: `ALTER USER` is an alias for `ALTER ROLE`

Comment: This can also be used to change passwords for other users: `\password username`

Comment: It does not find the \password   (on Linux)

Comment: @Coliban, you need to be on the `psql` prompt when you run it.

Comment: @Andy: yes, but psql didnt connected to DB for whatever reason. I´ve installed a new version with new passwords, now it is ok. Thank you

Comment: this worked for me, i couldn't run the ALTER USER command for some reason.

Comment: this worked for me, ALTER USER does not.. thanks!

Answer (score 132):

You can and should have the users' password encrypted:

```
ALTER USER username WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'password';
```

Comment: This keyword doesn't matter for the current version. From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html `The password is always stored encrypted in the system catalogs. The ENCRYPTED keyword has no effect, but is accepted for backwards compatibility.`

Comment: Beware! @John29 comment is only true from Postgresql 10 and above. For all other versions the ENCRYPTED flag matters.

Comment: the **unencrypted password  is rememberd by `psql` history** or shell... How to use hashed (ex. SHA1) password?

Comment: @PeterKrauss you might be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395538/postgres-md5-password-plain-password) Q&A

Answer (score 54):

To the change password:

```
 sudo -u postgres psql
```

Then

```
\password postgres
```

Now enter the *new password* and confirm.

Then `\q` to exit.

Comment: If I do that, it prompts for a password

Answer (score 52):

To change the password using the Linux command line, use:

```
sudo -u <user_name> psql -c "ALTER USER <user_name> PASSWORD '<new_password>';"
```

Comment: Just remember that this will probably save the db's user password in your command history.

Comment: can you use environment variables here? I want to automate this in a deploy script

Comment: Start the command with a space in the terminal and it should keep it out of your command history.

Comment: In bash, if `HISTCONTROL` is set to `ignorespace` or `ignoreboth`, then a command line starting with a space is not added to the history.

Answer (score 35):

Go to your PostgreSQL configuration and edit file *pg_hba.conf*:

`sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf`

Then change this line:

```
Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local      all              postgres                                md5
```

to:

```
Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

Then restart the PostgreSQL service via the 'sudo' command. Then

> `psql -U postgres`

You will be now entered and will see the PostgreSQL terminal.

Then enter

`\password`

And enter the *new* password for the PostgreSQL default user. After successfully changing the password again, go to the *pg_hba.conf* and revert the change to "md5".

Now you will be logged in as

```
psql -U postgres
```

with your new password.

Comment: It doesn't work : `user@user-NC10:~$ psql -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Comment: Ok,

Do another method

sudo su - postgres

psql

You will enter the terminal and then change the password there, This is an alternate way for this.

Let me know if this works for you or you need a full explanation

Comment: mm i have tried but I have another error:/usr/bin/psql: line 19: use: command not found
/usr/bin/psql: line 21: use: command not found
/usr/bin/psql: line 23: use: command not found
/usr/bin/psql: line 24: use: command not found
/usr/bin/psql: psql: line 26: syntax error near unexpected token `$version,'
/usr/bin/psql: psql: line 26: `my ($version, $cluster, $db, $port, $host);' thanks for your help!

Answer (score 24):

#### Setting up a password for the *postgres* role

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

You will get a prompt like the following:

```
postgres=#
```

#### Change password to PostgreSQL for user *postgres*

```
ALTER USER postgres WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'postgres';
```

You will get something as follows:

```
ALTER ROLE
```

#### To do this we need to edit the *pg_hba.conf* file.

(Feel free to replace [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) with an editor of your choice.)

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
```

#### Update in the *pg_hba.conf* file

Look for an uncommented line (a line that doesn’t start with *#*) that has the contents shown below. The spacing will be slightly different, but the words should be the same.

```
    local   postgres   postgres   peer
```

to

```
    local   postgres   postgres   md5
```

#### Now we need to restart PostgreSQL, so the changes take effect

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 17):

To request a new password for the **postgres** user (without showing it in the command):

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "\password"
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are on Windows.

Open `pg_hba.conf` file and change from `md5` to `peer`.

Open cmd and type `psql postgres postgres`.

Then type `\password` to be prompted for a new password.

[Refer to this Medium post](https://medium.com/@tmacharia/how-to-change-postgresql-password-f1efba2f160) for further information & granular steps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26405280)

Comment: Thanks @BrianMinton for the heads up.

Comment: it worked for me using `trust` instead of `peer`

Answer (score 15):

This was the first result on google, when I was looking how to rename a user, so:

```
ALTER USER <username> WITH PASSWORD '<new_password>';  -- change password
ALTER USER <old_username> RENAME TO <new_username>;    -- rename user
```

A couple of other commands helpful for user management:

```
CREATE USER <username> PASSWORD '<password>' IN GROUP <group>;
DROP USER <username>;
```

Move user to another group

```
ALTER GROUP <old_group> DROP USER <username>;
ALTER GROUP <new_group> ADD USER <username>;
```

Answer (score 10):

The configuration that I've got on my server was customized a lot, and I managed to change the password only after I set **trust** authentication in the [`pg_hba.conf` file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html):

```
local   all   all   trust
```

Don't forget to change this back to password or md5.

Comment: you also need to restart your postgres service for changes to take effect `sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service`

Comment: where should this pg_hba.conf file go?

Answer (score 10):

Use this:

```
\password
```

Enter the new password you want for that user and then confirm it.
If you don't remember the password and you want to change it, you can log in as *"postgres"* and then use this:

```
ALTER USER 'the username' WITH PASSWORD 'the new password';
```

Answer (score 10):

For my case on [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr), installed with PostgreSQL 10.3: I need to follow the following steps

- `su - postgres` to switch the user to `postgres`
- `psql` to enter the PostgreSQL shell
- `\password` and then enter your password
- <kbd>Q</kbd> to quit the shell session
- Then you switch back to root by executing `exit` and configure your `pg_hba.conf` (mine is at `/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf`) by making sure you have the following line

  `local all   postgres    md5`
- Restart your PostgreSQL service by `service postgresql restart`
- Now switch to the `postgres` user and enter the PostgreSQL shell again. It will prompt you for a password.

Comment: I don't think you really need to restart the postgresql service after changing the password. I have been able to reset the password with restarting it. \password is the quickest way. Or else you need the ALTER USER command.

Answer (score 9):

For **Windows** using the **Command Prompt**:

1. Change the directory to the `/bin` of your `PostgreSQL` installation folder. Commonly we could use this command:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<version>\bin
   ```
2. Connect to PostgreSQL server as a superuser:

   ```
   psql -U postgres
   ```
3. Run the following command to change the superuser password:

   ```
   ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';
   ```

Answer (score 8):

**TLDR:**

On many systems, a user's account often contains a period, or some sort of punctuation (user: *john.smith*, *horise.johnson*).  In these cases, a modification will have to be made to the accepted answer above.  The change requires the username to be double-quoted.

#### Example

```
ALTER USER "username.lastname" WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

**Rationale:**

PostgreSQL is quite picky on when to use a 'double quote' and when to use a 'single quote'.  Typically, when providing a string, you would use a single quote.

Comment: The double quotes got me as well, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 8):

You can easily change the password by executing the following command line code:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD '<new password>'
```

However, it should be noted that your unencrypted password will still be visible in plaintext in the command line history.

It would be best if you also used the `ENCRYPTED` keyword explicitly if using PostgreSQL version 10 or less.

Answer (score 6):

Changing password of a PostgreSQL User is fairly simple task.
After starting Postgres, use the following command.

```
ALTER ROLE username   
WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

Instead of username write the user you want to alter and in '' where password is written, write the new password, you want for the user.

For further understanding, visit following article: [How To Change The Password of a PostgreSQL User](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-administration/postgresql-change-password/)

Answer (score 5):

This is similar to other answers in syntax, but it should be known that you can also pass the [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hash value of the password, so you are not transmitting a plain text password.

Here are a few scenarios of unintended consequences of altering a users password in plain text.

1. If you do not have [SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) and are modifying remotely you are transmitting the plain text password across the network.
2. If you have your logging configuration set to log [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements `log_statement = ddl` or higher, then your plain text password will show up in your error logs.
3. If you are not protecting these logs, it’s a problem.
4. If you collect these logs/[ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) them and display them where others have access, they could end up seeing this password, etc.
5. If you allow a user to manage their password, they are unknowingly revealing a password to an administrator or low-level employee tasked with reviewing logs.

With that said, here is how we can alter a user's password by building an MD5 hash value of the password.

- PostgreSQL, when hashing a password as MD5, salts the password with the user name and then prepends the text "md5" to the resulting hash.
- Example: "md5"+md5(password + username)
- In Bash:

  ```
  echo -n "passwordStringUserName" | md5sum | awk '{print "md5"$1}'
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  md5d6a35858d61d85e4a82ab1fb044aba9d
  ```
- In PowerShell:

  ```
  [PSCredential] $Credential = Get-Credential

  $StringBuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder

  $null = $StringBuilder.Append('md5');

  [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create('md5').ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(((ConvertFrom-SecureStringToPlainText -SecureString $Credential.Password) + $Credential.UserName))) | ForEach-Object {
      $null = $StringBuilder.Append($_.ToString("x2"))
  }

  $StringBuilder.ToString();

  ## OUTPUT
  md5d6a35858d61d85e4a82ab1fb044aba9d
  ```
- So finally our `ALTER USER` command will look like

  ```
  ALTER USER UserName WITH PASSWORD 'md5d6a35858d61d85e4a82ab1fb044aba9d';
  ```
- Relevant links (note I will only link to the latest versions of the documentation. For older, it changes some, but MD5 is still supported a ways back.)
- *[create role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html)*
- > The password is always stored encrypted in the system catalogs. The ENCRYPTED keyword has no effect, but is accepted for backwards compatibility. The method of encryption is determined by the configuration parameter password_encryption. If the presented password string is already in MD5-encrypted or SCRAM-encrypted format, then it is stored as-is regardless of password_encryption (since the system cannot decrypt the specified encrypted password string, to encrypt it in a different format). This allows reloading of encrypted passwords during dump/restore.
- Configuration setting for [password_encryption](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-PASSWORD-ENCRYPTION)
- [PostgreSQL password authentication documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/auth-password.html)
- [Building PostgreSQL password MD5 hash value](https://evanhoffman.com/2014/02/12/setting-user-postgres-passwords-via-md5/)

Answer (score 5):

And the fully automated way with Bash and expect ([in this example](https://github.com/YordanGeorgiev/qto/blob/master/src/bash/qto/funcs/provision-db-admin.func.sh) we provision a new PostgreSQL administrator with the newly provisioned PostgreSQL password both on OS and PostgreSQL run-time level):

```bash
  # The $postgres_usr_pw and the other Bash variables MUST be defined
  # for reference the manual way of doing things automated with expect bellow
  #echo "copy-paste: $postgres_usr_pw"
  #sudo -u postgres psql -c "\password"
  # The OS password could / should be different
  sudo -u root echo "postgres:$postgres_usr_pw" | sudo chpasswd

  expect <<- EOF_EXPECT
     set timeout -1
     spawn sudo -u postgres psql -c "\\\password"
     expect "Enter new password: "
     send -- "$postgres_usr_pw\r"
     expect "Enter it again: "
     send -- "$postgres_usr_pw\r"
     expect eof
EOF_EXPECT

  cd /tmp/
  # At this point the 'postgres' executable uses the new password
  sudo -u postgres PGPASSWORD=$postgres_usr_pw psql \
    --port $postgres_db_port --host $postgres_db_host -c "
  DO \$\$DECLARE r record;
     BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT
           FROM   pg_catalog.pg_roles
           WHERE  rolname = '"$postgres_db_useradmin"') THEN
              CREATE ROLE "$postgres_db_useradmin" WITH SUPERUSER CREATEROLE
              CREATEDB REPLICATION BYPASSRLS
 PASSWORD '"$postgres_db_useradmin_pw"' LOGIN ;
        END IF;
     END\$\$;
  ALTER ROLE "$postgres_db_useradmin" WITH SUPERUSER CREATEROLE
  CREATEDB REPLICATION BYPASSRLS
PASSWORD  '"$postgres_db_useradmin_pw"' LOGIN ;
 "
```

Answer (score 5):

I was on Windows (Windows Server 2019; PostgreSQL 10), so `local` type connections (`pg_hba.conf`: `local  all  all  peer`) are not supported.

The following should work on Windows and Unix systems alike:

1. backup `pg_hba.conf` to `pg_hba.orig.conf` e.g.
2. create `pg_hba.conf` with only this: `host  all  all  127.0.0.1/32  trust`
3. restart pg (service)
4. execute `psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1`
5. enter (in pgctl console) `alter user postgres with password 'SomePass';`
6. restore `pg_hba.conf` from 1. above

Answer (score 5):

Change password to "postgres" for user "postgres":

```
# ALTER USER postgres WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '<NEW-PASSWORD>';
```

Comment: What is "#"? The prompt from executable "psql"?

Answer (score 5):

To interactively change/assign the password of an *existing* user in the `psql` shell

```bash
\password <username>
# you will be prompted for the password that you want to define
```

If you leave the username blank, it will prompt you to change the password of the 'postgres' user by default.

Answer (score 4):

One hacky way of changing your pgsql password is executing this command in the terminal as a **superuser**

```
ALTER USER username WITH PASSWORD 'your password'
```

You may have to restart your server for this to take effect.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Isn't this basically the same thing that the [11 year old answer with 2300+ upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12721095/3962537) says (not to mention the other half-dozen or so near duplicates)? Regurgitating already existing content adds no value.

Answer (score 3):

In general, just use the [pgAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Database_administration) UI for doing database-related activity.

If instead you are focusing more in automating database setup for your local development, [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration), etc.

For example, you can use a simple combination like this.

(a) Create a dummy super user via [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29) with a command similar to this:

```
docker exec -t postgres11-instance1 createuser --username=postgres --superuser experiment001
```

This will create a super user called *experiment001* in you PostgreSQL database.

(b) Give this user some password by running a NON-Interactive SQL command.

```
docker exec -t postgres11-instance1 psql -U experiment001 -d postgres -c "ALTER USER experiment001 WITH PASSWORD 'experiment001' "
```

PostgreSQL is probably the best database out there for command line (non-interactive) tooling. Creating users, running SQL, making backup of database, etc.

In general, it is all quite basic with PostgreSQL, and it is overall quite trivial to integrate this into your development setup scripts or into automated CI configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Check file *pg_hba.conf*.

In case the authentication method is 'peer', the client's operating system user name/password must match the database user name and password. In that case, set the password for Linux user 'postgres' and the DB user 'postgres' to be the same.

See the documentation for details: *[19.1. The pg_hba.conf File](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)*

Comment: Yes, this dependency is seldom mentioned. Is it the default?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers were mostly correct, but you need to look out for minor things. The problem I had was that I didn't ever set the password of "postgres", so I couldn't log into an SQL command line that allowed me to change passwords. These are the steps that I used successfully (note that most or all commands need sudo or root user):

- Edit the `pg_hba.conf` file in the data directory of the DB cluster you're trying to connect to.

  - The folder of the data directory can be found by inspecting the [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) command line, easily obtained with `systemctl status postgresql@VERSION-DB_CLUSTER`. Replace VERSION with your [psql](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Database_administration) version and DB_CLUSTER with the name of your database cluster. This may be main if it was automatically created, so, e.g., `postgresql@13-main`. Alternatively, my Bash shell provided auto-complete after entering `postgresql@`, so you could try that or look for the PostgreSQL services in the list of all services (`systemctl -a`). Once you have the status output, look for the second command line after CGroup, which should be rather long, and start with `/usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/postgres` or similar (depending on version, distro, and installation method). You are looking for the directory after `-D`, for example `/var/lib/postgresql/13/main`.
- Add the following line: `host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust`. This allows for all users on all databases to connect to the database via [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) on the local machine **unconditionally, without asking for a password**.

  This is a temporary fix and don't forget to remove this line again later on. Just to be sure, I commented out the `host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5` (*md5* may be replaced by *scram-sha-256*), which is valid for the same login data, just requiring a password.
- Restart the database service: `systemctl restart postgresql@...` Again, use the exact service you found earlier.
- Check that the service started properly with `systemctl status postgresql@...`.
- Connect with *psql*, and very importantly, **force psql to not ask for a password**. In my experience, it will ask you for a password even though the server doesn't care, and will still reject your login if your password was wrong. This can be accomplished with the `-w` flag.

  The full command line looks something like this: `sudo -u postgres psql -w -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432`. Here, `postgres` is your user and you may have changed that. `5432` is the port of the cluster-specific server and may be higher if you are running more than one cluster (I have 5434 for example).
- Change the password with the `\password` special command.
- **Remember to remove the password ignore workaround and restart the server to apply the configuration.**

Answer (score 1):

Using [pgAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Database_administration) 4:

Menu *Object* → *Change password...*

Answer (score 1):

For those intend to use it in a **CI/CD pipeline**, an alternative is to use Clint Bugs' one line solution, and assign the password to a global variable:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD '$PGPASSWORD';"
```

Considering, of course, reading the documentation of the CI/CD tool (I used [Semaphore](https://docs.semaphoreci.com/ci-cd-environment/sem-service-managing-databases-and-services-on-linux/)), for the definition of the value of this global variable.

Answer (score 0):

It worked:

1. Put only one entry in pg_hba.conf.
   host all all ::1/128  trust
2. Make sure that you run cmd from administrator if windows
   pg_ctl reload -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\Data"
3. start psql and it won't ask for the password and connect.
4. Now reset the password.
   postgres=# alter user postgres with password 'postgres';
   ALTER ROLE
5. Now go to Pgadmin and provide the password.
   connected...Bingo!