# ROR + PgAdmin + psql: FATAL: role "user1234" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my sample project, I am trying to create postgre database. While running the rake db:create, I am getting some strange message and unable to create the database.

```
user1234@ubuntu:~/Development/example$ psql -d postgres
psql: FATAL:  role "user1234" does not exist
user1234@ubuntu:~/Development/example$ psql -d postgres -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
user1234@ubuntu:~/Development/example$ psql -d postgres -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Please suggest me, what will be my next step to resolve this issue and to make my sample project in running state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long fight and lot of RnD, I have decided to `create one more user for postgres` from pgAdmin.

[image: FirstImage- Add New User]

[image: Second Image - Add Password]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you only set up *peer identification* in your `pg_haba.conf` file.

Try in your Ubuntu shell

```
sudo su postgres
psql
```

More information under these related questions:
[PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist/11919677)
[pgadmin gives me the error: no password supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035742/pgadmin-gives-me-the-error-no-password-supplied/14042436#14042436)
[Run batch file with psql command without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable feedback. But after a lot of struggle, I made one more user and added to config.yml now it is working fine.