# What is the default username and password for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I am working on an open source application that has PostgreSQL as its default [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database#Database_management_system). Now when I install it on my system, its configuration is so that PostgreSQL also gets installed with it.

My problem is with getting access to the installed PostgreSQL database. The database that gets created during installation is named `iviewdb`.

I read at many forums that the default superuser is `postgres`, but when I try to get access to the database using this username through a command prompt, it prompts me for password that I don't have.

I wanted to know from where in the PostgreSQL installation directory
the default username and password with the port number to access the database is stored. I have even tried changing the `pg_hba.conf` file, but that creates a problem with the application and it won't start then.

How can I find the password for this database? I am working in a Windows environment.

Comment: The password for the superuser account is provided by you when you run `initdb` (or during the installation)

Comment: Related: *[Is "postgres" a default and special user of PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50883645/is-postgres-a-default-and-special-user-of-postgresql)*

Answer (score 7):

I've encountered this similar problem, and I noticed that the default being set for PostgreSQL upon installation in my case is as follows:

username = postgres 
password = ' '

Answer (score 6):

The password isn't stored in an easily recoverable manner, and if you change the password, the application may not be able to access the database properly.  You may find the password in the application settings or documentation, though.

If you decide to risk changing the *postgres* user's password, stop the application and PostgreSQL service, and then edit *pg_hba.conf*. Add (or change if it already exists) a line (if it doesn't exist, add it before any other "host...." lines):

```
host   all   all   127.0.0.1/32   trust
```

And restart the PostgreSQL service.  That should give you access from [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), where you could change the *postgres* user's password, or add yourself another user with the permissions you want.  Then set the *pg_hba.conf* file back the way it was and restart.

Comment: Much better to take the second route and add yourself another user, if the application documentation doesn't include the default password.

Comment: There is no need to stop Postgres to change pg_hba.conf After editing it, a simple `pg_ctl reload` will apply the changed settings.