# Is "postgres" a default and special user of PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

1. *[Chapter 21. Database Roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/default-roles.html%20lists)* lists the default roles of PostgreSQL. But I don't find user `postgres` there,
   which has been created by default in PostgreSQL. Is `postgres` a
   default role? Does the manual miss it or do I misunderstand?
2. In PostgreSQL, is `postgres` a special user, or a regular user just
   like one created manually?  Does the PostgreSQL server need the user `postgres`? Will removing it cause some trouble to the server or something else?
3. The following two commands run in *psql* provide default roles or
   usernames, which both include `postgres`. Why do they differ?

   ```
   # select usename from pg_catalog.pg_user;

    usename
   ----------
    postgres
   (1 row)

   # select rolname from pg_catalog.pg_roles;

          rolname
   ----------------------
    postgres
    pg_monitor
    pg_read_all_settings
    pg_read_all_stats
    pg_stat_scan_tables
    pg_signal_backend
   (6 rows)
   ```

Comment: This page is reproduced without any attribution at `techhelpnotes DOT com/is-postgres-a-default-and-special-user-of-postgresql/` (that is, plagiarised).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `postgres` is *not* a default role.

   When you create the PostgreSQL database cluster with `initdb`, you can specify the name of the installation superuser with the `-U` option. If you omit that option, the name of the superuser will be the same as the name of the operating system user you are using.

   Since it is customary to have `initdb` PostgreSQL run by an operating system user `postgres`, the superuser is usually called `postgres` too, but that isn't in any way required.
2. `postgres` is just a normal superuser like any other.

   You will have trouble dropping it because it owns all the system objects, and you cannot easily modify those objects. You are advised not to try.
3. `pg_read_all_settings` and the others don't show up in `pg_user` because they are not login roles.

Comment: Thanks. 1.  " If you omit that option, the name of the superuser will be the same as the name of the operating system user you are using."  I have never created a user "postgres" on my OS Lubuntu 18.04, so how can "postgres" be used as the name of the superuser? 3. " they are no login roles."  Is it correct that login roles are exactly users and nonlogin roles are exactly groups?

Comment: 1. On LUbuntu 18.04, I installed postgresql by `sudo apt install postgresql`

Comment: Installing the package on Ubuntu automatically creates a Unix user "postgres".  You can see that user in /etc/passwd.

Comment: @Tim Yes, a user in PostgreSQL is the same as a role that can login. Normally nologin roles are used as groups, but that is not a requirement.

Comment: Thanks. "nologin roles are used as groups, but that is not a requirement." Do you mean a nonlogin role may still be a user not a group?

Comment: Free yourself from the concept of users and groups. Some roles can login. Roles can be members of other roles.

Comment: Thanks again. Also appreciate it if you could consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50910984/distinctions-between-users-and-groups-in-postgresql

Answer (score 2):

`postgres` is the first user that is available after an installation. it is a super user. But, it is possible to define your own super users which will have equivalent permissions to the `postgres` user.

A user is a role that has the ability to log in.

Roles without login privilege are used for various system level uses and are sometimes also used to manage access control rules through inheritance (e.g. you may have a role `analysts` and a user `hal` that is granted membership to the `analysts` role)

Thus `pg_user` only returns those roles that are able to log into the database.

Comment: Thanks. (1) why is `postgres` not listed as default role in the link? (2) Is it correct that a user == a role which can log in, and, a group == a role which can't log in? (3) Does the PostgreSQL server need the user `postgres`? WIll removing it cause some trouble to the server or something else? (4) Is there a command to show whether a user such as `postgres` is a superuser, and a command which can show all the superusers?

Comment: 1 - see other answer from laurenz. 2 - yes. 3 - no, but deleting is tricky and you have to transfer all objects owned by postgres to other user(s). 4 - select rolname from pg_catalog.pg_roles where rolsuper will show all roles that are super