# Distinctions between users and groups in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

From [Is postgres a default and special user of PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50883645/is-postgres-a-default-and-special-user-of-postgresql/50884736?noredirect=1#comment88783902_50884736)

> a user in PostgreSQL is the same as a role that can login. Normally
>   nologin roles are used as groups, but that is not a requirement.
>
> Free yourself from the concept of users and groups. Some roles can
>   login. Roles can be members of other roles.

Basically, concepts of user and group are merged into role. But it seems to me there are still distinctions.

"nologin roles are used as groups, but that is not a requirement." 
Does that mean

- a nonlogin role may still be a user not a group?
- a login roles can be a group?

"Roles can be members of other roles", does that mean

- a group can be a member of another role, and can the other role be a user?
- a role can be a member of a user, and can that role be a group?

Thanks.

Comment: Being able to log into database is the only technical difference between those two. Everything else is the same.

Comment: I couldn't have put it better than @ŁukaszKamiński

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński  Thanks.  can you show that a group can be a member of a user or a member of another group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is with respect to login

Quoting [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/role-membership.html) below:

> CREATE USER is now an alias for CREATE ROLE. The only difference is that when the command is spelled CREATE USER, LOGIN is assumed by default, whereas NOLOGIN is assumed when the command is spelled CREATE ROLE.

In general, there's no separate concept of user/group. There are only roles. And a role can be a member of other roles. And a role can also have a set of attributes like "SUPERUSER", "CREATEDB" etc., and "LOGIN" happens to be just one of them.

Comment: Thanks. can you show that a group can be a member of a user or a member of another group?