# port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user 'postgres'

Tags: postgresql, macos-monterey

I installed postgresql 14 version on macOS Monterey, but I get this error when entering my password.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CXXh.jpg)

I tried to edit pg_hba.conf, set 'trust' method instead 'scram-sha-256' but it's doesn't help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEd8X.png)

Comment: If you're running a default installation there is no role "postgres" by default anymore (but default database name is still postgres). It's actually your system user name. You can check the roles by running `psql postgres` and then in the psql console `\du`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite clear, do you mean that the postgres user does not exist? what should I do in this case?

Comment: run psql - terminal-based front-end for Postgres. To change username in the pgadmin right click on "PostgreSQL 14" and change username from "Postgres" to your Mac username. Login without password.

Comment: You only changed the method for IPv4 connections, but you are trying to make an IPv6 connection.

Comment: @Revuimar, you are making a sweeping statement about the role `postgres` that is simply not true. It is created by default in many instances. If you are referring to a specific situation then you need to elaborate on that.

Comment: @jjanes yeah, I changed all methods on 'trust' and add picture too, bit it also doesn't help

Comment: @AdrianKlaver [That's what I meant.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50883645/is-postgres-a-default-and-special-user-of-postgresql) The issue of default user created in the cluster initialisation is pretty confusing for people new to postgres. As many tutorials forget to mention it and write `postgres` as customary default. [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-initdb.html)

Comment: Because in most cases it is as the default  as installations generally run as the postgres system user and/or have the  `initdb -U postgres`. You will be more correct expecting their to be a `postgres` role then there not being one. Now [postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com/) is an exception to this, but it has not been established that the OP is using it. So rather then muddy the waters, ask how the OP installed Postgres?