# How to connect Postgres to localhost server using pgAdmin on Ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, pgadmin

I installed Postgres with this command

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-client postgresql-contrib libpq-dev
```

Using `psql --version` on terminal I get `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.4`

then I installed `pgadmin` with

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

Later I opened the UI and create the server with this information

[image]

but this error appear

[image]

how can I fix it?

Comment: download postgresql of v9.3 from this link [https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads#windows](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads#windows) and again run pgadmin III you will get local host already install need not to connect.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You haven't created a user `db`. If its just a fresh install, the default user is `postgres` and the password should be blank. After you access it, you can create the users you need.

Comment: If I do that, this error appear  ``Error connecting to the server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied``

Comment: Here on opensuse the postgres user password is not blank, but undefined (an exclamation mark in /etc/shadow). No password login possible.

Comment: Just tested to verify, and yes, Pg does emit `password authentication failed` for a user that doesn't exist when using `md5` auth.

Comment: @CraigRinger I just checked a default pg_hba.conf, and you are correct. The default is peer or md5.

Comment: how do you create a user?

Comment: "Error connecting to the server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied"

Answer (score 226):

Modify password for role postgres:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres

alter user postgres with password 'postgres';
```

Now connect to pgadmin using username postgres and password postgres

Now you can create roles & databases using pgAdmin

[How to change PostgreSQL user password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720967/is-possible-to-check-or-change-postgresql-user-password)

Comment: or you can just.. 'sudo -u postgres psql' and then type '\password'. hit enter. enter new password.

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Thank you. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 29):

It helps me:

---

1. **Open the file** `pg_hba.conf`

> sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.x/main/pg_hba.conf

and change this line:

```
Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5
```

to

```
Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                trust
```

2. **Restart the server**

   > sudo service postgresql restart
3. **Login into psql** and **set password**

   > psql -U postgres

`ALTER USER postgres with password 'new password';`

4. Again **open the file** `pg_hba.conf` and change this line:

```
Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
    local   all             postgres                                trust
```

to

```
    Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
    local   all             postgres                                md5
```

5. **Restart the server**

   > sudo service postgresql restart

---

It works.

[image]

---

Helpful links 
1: [PostgreSQL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL) (from ubuntu.com)

Comment: This solved my problem, but can you explain why changing the db admin login to trust prior to setting the postgres password is needed in some instances?

Comment: @HostMyBus Hi man, actually I don't recall at all this case. Try to dig some answers from the web (i think there is a good explanation about that)

Comment: @HostMyBus this is a security feature. If it is set to trust, any user on the machine can login to the database.

Comment: And you actually don't need it: Just use WiredIn answer

Answer (score 4):

Create a user first. You must do this as user postgres. Because the postgres system account has no password assigned, you can either set a password first, or you go like this:

```
sudo /bin/bash
# you should be root now  
su postgres
# you are postgres now
createuser --interactive
```

and the programm will prompt you.

Comment: `sudo -u postgres -i` will lead to password question. There is no password on my system you can enter. My proposal works always (hm, hopefully).

Comment: `sudo -u postgress -i` doesn't lead to password question (at least on my Ubuntu after default installation). Either the `createuser --interactive` doesn't lead to the password prompt... :(

Comment: @OndřejDoněk my proposal was sudo /bin/bash first, did you do that?

Comment: what should you type in for role?

Comment: $ `createuser --interactive`

Enter name of role to add: `postgres`

Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) `y`

Answer (score 3):

First you should change the password using terminal. 
(username is postgres)

postgres=# \password postgres

Then you will be prompted to enter the password and confirm it.

Now you will be able to connect using pgadmin with the new password.

Answer (score 0):

if you open the `psql` console in a terminal window, by typing

$ `psql`

you're super user username will be shown before the `=#`, for example:

`elisechant=#`$

That will be the user name you should use for localhost.