# Unable to connect to server pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

When attempting to add a server (this is my first install)

Configuration:

postgres 12

centos 7

pgadmin 4

I get

```
could not connect to server: Permission denied
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting    
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Permission denied
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

per

```
SHOW listen_addresses;
listen_addresses 
------------------
localhost
```

I can network connect from psql

```
psql -h localhost aps19
psql (12.1, server 9.2.24)
Type "help" for help.

aps19=>
```

I am listening on port 5432

I am able to make TCP connections from java from my localhost
    postgres>psql
    psql (12.1, server 9.2.24)
    Type "help" for help.

```
xxx=> show port   
xxx-> ;
port 
------
5432
```

per [How connect Postgres to localhost server using pgAdmin on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917832/how-connect-postgres-to-localhost-server-using-pgadmin-on-ubuntu)

psql (12.1, server 9.2.24)
Type "help" for help.

```
postgres=# 
postgres=# alter user postgres with password 'postgres';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=#
```

also

```
netstat -a | grep 5432
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     30611    /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     30602    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Answer (score 1):

use the "ifconfig" cmd to find real docker ip which name is dock0.

And then use it as username to login.

Comment: Or you can try "host.docker.internal" that is the same real docker IP as username to login.