# pgAdmin can't connect to the local database server

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I've just updated pgAdmin to version 4.23 and PostgreSQL to version 12. I've also deleted all previous databases and pgAdmin installations. So it should have been a clean install (I've also cleaned up all the remains of previous versions).

Now when I'm attempting to connect to the local database server I get this before I can even type my password:

`could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5433? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5433?`

The service is running, I can use command line tool and it responds correctly but I can't use pgAdmin for some reason.

```
>psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.3
```

Comment: Change your `listen_address` in` postgresql.conf ` and `pg_hba.conf`

Answer (score 2):

A duplicate of your question

[PostgreSQL database service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482239/postgresql-database-service)

Look through this thread as it states multiple solutions

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917832/how-connect-postgres-to-localhost-server-using-pgadmin-on-ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482239/postgresql-database-service)

Comment: most of them are about changing a password or changing `pg_hba.conf` file. I tried that before the re-installation as well as after and it does absolutely nothing. At least, during re-installation it created `postgres` user and I was able to give it a password. Now I can log on and manually do things with the command line tool. But not with pgAdmin, and that's really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

To access PostgreSQL over the network

Change `listen_address` localhost to `*` in file `/etc/postgresql/{version_number}/main/postgresql.conf`

```
# - Connection Settings - 
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

Changes in `pg_hba.conf`

Add the following line in # IPv4 local connections:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

and comment

```
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

Comment: did absolutely nothing.

Comment: You need to restart the database.

Comment: how do I do that?.. I have stopped the service before and restarted it after making changes to the file. Is there another way?