# Psycopg2 peer authentication for user postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, ubuntu-16.04

I seem to have correctly installed PostgreSQL 9.5.5. and Psycopg2 on Ubuntu 16.04, and can log in via:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

If I then issue `\conninfo`, I get the following:

```
You are connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432".
```

Surely I should be able to connect via psycopg2 in the same fashion as shown [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html), but the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres") 
conn.close()
```

gives me:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I only want PostgreSQL for personal usage, so I don't want to enable TCP authentication.

How do I correctly use peer authentication with user "postgres" in Psycopg2?

Comment: Are you using `sudo -u postgres` to run your Python script?

Comment: Thanks, running as `sudo -u postgres` fixes everything. Can you post this as an answer, so that I can accept?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Peer authentication works by comparing the Postgres username in your connection string to the name of the Linux user who is running the script.

Try running your Python script with `sudo -u postgres`.

Comment: What if your script needs as well to write some files (such as log files) out to a directory owned by $USER, the logged in user, which is not the `postgres` user? Because when running the script with `sudo -u postgres` you will hit the following error: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: /home/${USER}/.../my_log_file`.

Comment: @s.k: If you created a database user called `$USER`, then you could use peer authentication without the `sudo`. You could also separate the file-writing and the database access (e.g. write a sub-script which logs to `stdout`, call the script with `sudo` and redirect the output). If you really need to connect as `postgres`, but can't run the rest of the script as `postgres`, then you'll need to enable a different authentication method (though the security implications of this are a bit much to cover in comments).

Answer (score 27):

You need to supply the host

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='template1' user='dbuser' host='localhost' password='dbpass'")
```

Comment: Question specifies `PEER` authentication.

Comment: This is not the correct answer for the user "postgres" but explicitly adding "localhost" (rather than an empty string) as the host in django's settings.py made the difference for me.

Comment: For me it also made the difference just to add `host='localhost'`, now it's working. The other answer saying "run your python script with `sudo -u postgres`" is not my preferred solution because I want this authentification to happen within the python script, or even be able to run it interactively in a jupyter notebook or iPython.

Answer (score 3):

This is sort of how yoru call should look like.

```
!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres", user="postgres", password="postgres", port=5432)

conn.close()
```

Comment: This gives me `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"` and I thought password implies TCP authentication. How do I set up localhost?

Comment: Now I'm back to `psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Comment: Can you enable password less login and remove the pw field  from the connection? sudo -u postgres psql postgres

Comment: Look here to change postgres pw - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720967/how-to-change-postgresql-user-password

Comment: I've read that putting a password on the default postgres user changes the authentication, and I'd like to avoid that. Thanks

Comment: Question specifies `PEER` authentication.

Answer (score 2):

these are the some authentication method of postgresql

**peer**  means it will trust the identity (authenticity) of UNIX user. So not asking for a password.

**md5** means it will always ask for a password, and validate it after hashing with MD5.

**trust** means it will never ask for a password, and always trust any connection.

I your case youe have to cahnge like this:

**host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident**

to

**host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5**

and

**host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident**

to

**host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5**