# change database username and password in Postgres.app

Tags: database, postgresql, passwords, postgresapp

I have just downloaded Postgres.app and set up a database to connect to with a Java program. By default, Postgres.app sets up a database server with a default username and no password. How can I secure my database with a password?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change PostgreSQL user password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720967/how-to-change-postgresql-user-password)