# Ruby on Rails/Postgres - How can I create a new database for a user that doesn't exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ubuntu

I've cloned a repository, and set up everything via a virtual machine loaded with Ubuntu and using RVM. Everything regarding Ruby on Rails was installed via RVM.

My issue is that, my Ubuntu login is different to the user that I assume the data base wants. Example, my Ubuntu login is Matt, but when I start rails server and load into the localhost:3000, it is saying this:

```
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError
FATAL: role "James" does not exist
```

I understand this is a postgres error, but what should I do now to make this work? I've search through the previous StackOverflow answers and the methods just don't work.

Eg. I've changed

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

to

```
local   all             postgres                                trust
```

Or using `psql -h localhost -U postgres` or `sudo -u postgres createuser -s $(whoami); createdb $(whoami)` and again, it doesn't work. The first command asks for a password, which I can't figure out.

Comment: The password for `sudo -u postgres createuser -s $(whoami);` is whatever you want the password for the postgres role to be. But I would really name the default postgres account something different than your OS username like for example `pg_user`. The only reason you would want them to be the same is for a passwordless ident authentication.

Comment: This QA might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720967/how-to-change-postgresql-user-password

Comment: You'll want to look at your config/database.yml file.  The problem probably isn't with Postgres, it's with your Rails configuration.  By default, with no `user:` listed, Rails will attempt to connect with the name of the user that started the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the user Rails uses to connect to PostgreSQL by editing `<project_root>/config/database.yml` ([source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-ruby-on-rails-with-postgres)).

Also, the reason your first `psql` command didn't work is `-h localhost` requires a `host` entry in `pg_hba.conf`, not `local`. You can omit the `-h localhost` for the `local` entry to take effect since the default is to connect via a local socket.

Comment: Where the rails gem is installed is not relevant to where his configuration files are.  They would be relative to the project _using_ rails, not the gem itself.