# How to set/reset password for PostgreSQL on Mac?

Tags: postgresql, macos

I'm trying to set up PostgreSQL on Mac, and having some difficulty figuring out my password.  I used homebrew to install with `brew install postgresql`, which appears to have executed correctly.  When I try to start postgreSQL with `psql postgres` I am prompted to enter the password for my user account.  I never actually set up a password, and my general user account password fails the password authentication.  Same with `sudo psql postgres`.

I checked to see if I could change the `pg_hba.conf` file, but the file either doesn't exist or is not located at `/var/lib/postgres/data/pg_hba.conf`.  Any thoughts on how to reset my password?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change PostgreSQL user password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720967/how-to-change-postgresql-user-password)

Comment: You may be connecting to your macs pre-installed version of postgresql, which you'll need to sudo/su to  in order to connect to.

Answer (score 2):

In Homebrew 2.5.7 the installation of postgresql is at /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql and the configuration file is at /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf.

Answer (score 0):

In Homebrew 4.1.5 the config file is in

```
/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@<version>
```