# how to change Postgresql docker image password

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have created a Postgresql docker image using the following command on Windows:

```
docker run --name airdb-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=post1234 -d -p 5432:5432 postgres:alpine
```

is it possible to change the password I assigned to it, or I should create a new one by disposing this image?

Comment: Name of the environment variable is `PGPASSWORD` not `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` (of course provided that there is already a user with this password). However can you please elaborate on what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I wasn't sure how it is possible to change the password of a postgresql docker image. I realized I can do it after logging into the container @mic4ael .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to do that by logging into the container

```bash
docker exec -it <container_id> bash
```

then use `psql` cli to change the password.

See [How to change PostgreSQL user password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720967/how-to-change-postgresql-user-password) for the latter part.

Comment: I get:

> psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

Comment: @NessDan what command gave you that error?

Comment: @NessDan By default, it will log you in as a the user you are using if you do not have any arguments specified. Which, if you connect to the database using the `docker exec` command, will be `root`. You can specify the database name and the username within the `psql` command. Example: `psql mydatabase myuser`.

See `psql --help` for more information about the command.

Answer (score 2):

When I was upgrading postgres 12 to 15 for some reason my user passwords weren't working after the backup and restore. I was able to change fix it by doing the following. On windows I used git bash to run these commands.

bash

```bash
cat reset_password.sql | docker exec -i your-db-container-id psql -U postgres
```

reset_password.sql

```sql
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'mysecretpassword';

ALTER USER oc_admin WITH PASSWORD 'mysecretpassword';
```