# How to make use the PASSWORD with the official postgres docker image?

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, connection

Trying to make use of the official postgres docker image with:

```bash
docker run --rm -d \
        --name my-postgres \
        --network my-network \
        -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
        -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysuperduperlongpwstring \
        -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres \
        -v /path/to/postgres/data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        postgres
```

However, when creating postgres connection with Go,

```golang
        psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf(
                "host=%s port=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=%s",
                os.Getenv("DB_HOST"),
                os.Getenv("DB_PORT"),
                os.Getenv("DB_USER"),
                os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
                os.Getenv("DB_NAME"),
                os.Getenv("DB_SSL_MODE"),
        )
        db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
```

I always ended up with

`panic: pq: password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

and I have no any other ways to verify `mysuperduperlongpwstring`:

- Trying to make the DB connect from within docker container with `psql -U postgres -d postgres --password`, and give anything as password would work just fine.
- Trying to make change to the password from within docker container, will get

`ERROR:  must be superuser to alter replication roles or change replication attribute`

I.e., basically the answers from the following are not working for me any more:

- [how to change Postgresql docker image password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58643652/how-to-change-postgresql-docker-image-password)
- [How can I change a PostgreSQL user password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720967/how-can-i-change-a-postgresql-user-password)

Lacking of any resources, I've changed `mysuperduperlongpwstring` several times when starting docker, and change my Go PW accordingly, but every time I ended up with the same failure.

How to troubleshoot where the problem is please?
How to reset the PASSWORD with the official postgres docker?

Comment: That depends on an awful lot of env variables we can't see.  Maybe some of them are wrong.

Comment: Please expect people to have the most basic programming and error checking skills, which even undergrads would have @jjanes. If you don't believe me, then at least try to make other errors yourself in any of the env variables and see if you were still able to get _"password authentication failed"_.

Comment: "try to make other errors yourself " Easily enough done.  Put in the env the wrong hostname (or port) which links to a different running database instance.  Or quite obviously the wrong username or password, even if linked to the correct instance.  I've done it, I've seen other people do it, it is trivially easy to do.

Comment: "Please expect people to have the most basic programming and error checking skills, which even undergrads would have"  Long experience here has taught me not to expect that.  Especially from people who don't voluntarily share the needed information; or apparently look in the log file of the running server to say what is found there (which maybe be different or more expansive than what the client reports)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a docker container set up the say you show and starting from an empty volume, 'postgres' would be a superuser, and so you would not get the error about it needing to be a superuser.

The only plausible explanations I see for that part is either you didn't run psql where you thought you did, or you didn't start with an empty volume and so your `docker run` command just started up an existing database and thus your "-e POSTGRES*" configurations were all ignored.  So one way or another, you are either not connecting to what you think you are, or it is not configured the way you think it is.

Comment: _"you didn't start with an empty volume"_, BINGO! So, is it still possible to fix the situation pls?

Answer (score 2):

it seems you have special characters in your super strong password which leads to this, look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353623/how-to-handle-special-characters-in-the-password-of-a-postgresql-url-connection), my suggestion is to use **url.QueryEscape** like this:

```
psqlInfo := fmt.SprintF("postgresql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s?sslmode=%s",
  os.Getenv("DB_USER"),
  url.QueryEscape(os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD")),
  os.Getenv("DB_HOST"),
  os.Getenv("DB_PORT"),
  os.Getenv("DB_NAME"),
  os.Getenv("DB_SSL_MODE"),
)
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know. as _I've changed mysuperduperlongpwstring several times when starting docker_, one reason was to get rid of any special characters in my PW. But thx for the reply. +1