# How to get local server back in postgres? (padmin4)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

By Mistake removed the local server in pgadmin4, how can I get it back? 
It's not showing under server section anymore.

Comment: You need to reenter the connection information. Open pgAdmin4, Select "Servers", in the menu bar select Object then choose  Create, Click server. Reenter the information that initially created it. Save it.

Comment: Tried that but every time using the password which i use to start pgadmin, it gives an error FATAL: Password authentication failed for user 'postgres'. Now what to do?

Comment: Then you or an administrator will need to change the password via command line. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720967/postgresql-how-to-change-postgresql-user-password) .

Comment: Did you succeed with @Belayer response?

Comment: @MwamiTovi ,I was not able to succeed atlast i had to reinstall it and rebuild my connection

Comment: Oh, ok. Sometimes uninstall/re-install does magic!!