# Helm Postgres password authentication failed

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I install the Bitnami Helm chart, using the example shown in the README:

```sh
helm install my-db \
  --namespace dar \
  --set postgresqlPassword=secretpassword,postgresqlDatabase=my-database \
  bitnami/postgresql
```

Then, following the instructions shown in the blurb which prints after the installation is successful I forward the port to port 5432 then try and connect:

```
PGPASSWORD="secretpassword" psql --host 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -d my-database -p 5432
```

But I get the following error:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

How can this be? Is the Helm chart buggy?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Buried deep in the [stable/postgresql issue tracker](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/16251#issuecomment-564964236) is the source of this very-hard-to-debug problem.

When you run `helm uninstall ...` it errs on the side of caution and doesn't delete the storage associated with the database you got when you first ran `helm install ...`.

This means that once you've installed Postgres once via Helm, the secrets will always be the same in subsequent installs, regardless of what the post-installation blurb tells you.

To fix this, you have to manually remove the persistent volume claim (PVC) which will free up the database storage.

```sh
kubectl delete pvc data-my-db-postgresql-0
```

(Or whatever the PVC associated with your initial Helm install was named.)

Now a subsequent `helm install ...` will create a brand-new PVC and login can proceed as expected.

Comment: Yes I also have run into the same problem once and deleting the PVC fixed it..

Comment: Thanks a lot, Almost tried a day your post helped me lot to fix the issue as 'kubectl delete pvc <pvc>' command

Comment: Thank you, my friend!! This pvc being retained issue is notorious!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has rescued me from half of day debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but wasn't able anymore to drop the PVC as we were running in prod from a restore.

I ended up updating the password as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56820201/840238):

```
sudo -u postgres psql

\password postgres
```