# problem when changing PostgreSql user password in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am newbie with Rails and here is my problem.

I created a Rails by this command

```
rails new freelancer --database=postgreesql
```

And I had no error, everything seems ok.
When I opened the file database.yml, here is what I got

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %> 
development:
<<: *default
database: freelancer_development
test:
<<: *default
database: freelancer_test
production:
<<: *default
database: freelancer_production
username: freelancer
password: <%= ENV['FREELANCER_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

So, I thought that I must set the User Password for thist PostgreSQL database.
I search and found this link [PostgreSQL: How to change PostgreSQL user password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720967/postgresql-how-to-change-postgresql-user-password), follow it and used this command

```
sudo -u freelancer psql freelancer_production
```

But it said to me that

```
sudo : unknown user : freelancer
sudo : unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I am very confusing with this problem because I defined freelancer above ?
Could you please give me some ideas ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, this is an issue about accessing the database, not necessarily related to rails. What you're facing is that postgres does not have a user called 'freelancer', thus you cannot access the db.

There are two ways of solving this issue:

**A. Create a database user for the 'freelance' user**

Basically what you want to do is:

- login as the root user and create a new user/role

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
> CREATE ROLE rolename LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'test_password';
```

There are [many references](https://ubiq.co/database-blog/how-to-create-user-with-superuser-privileges-in-postgresql/) on how to do this if you want to learn more

**B. Use the root postgres user to access the database**

In this case we just need to change `database.yml` file:

- set the username as `postgres`
- set the password the root password for your postgres database

---

All that said, please be aware that using a `SUPERUSER` role is not ideal and presents security risks. So never use it outside your localhost environment or in a database that holds important information.

Comment: The immediate problem is coming from sudo, not from PostgreSQL.  The problem is that the *OS user* "freelance" doesn't exist.

Comment: I absolutely missed that. Still the solution applies, because it is necessary to create the user on Postgres. Nice catch jjanes