# Cannot connect to postgres dabase running in docker with my credentials

Tags: postgresql, docker, symfony

I am following the symfony book on symfony.com to learn symfony. When I create my symfony project I update my docker-compose.yml like this (values for the db name, password and user are just example):

```
version: '3'

services:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-15}-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: testdb
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123
      POSTGRES_USER: test
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
      # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

volumes:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database_data:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

When running this command in CLI in the project folder:

`docker-compose up -d`

It will create new docker container running the postgres:[postgres docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdP8a.png)

The problem is when I try to connect to the postgres instance running in the container.
When I try to connect via PSQL CLI with credentials specified in the docker-compose.yaml I get this error:

> psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 57514 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "test"

However I can connect with credentials which were default when I create the symfony project.

Default configuration:

```
version: '3'

services:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-15}-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-app}
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-app}
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
      # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

volumes:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database_data:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

So when I connect with user app and password !ChangeMe! it will connect.

I am on windows 10

I tried to configure the docker-compose.yml but with no succes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice this waning from [the postgres image docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres):

> the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup

If you first started this container with some values for POSTGRES_USER, POSTGRES_DB and POSTGRES_PASSWORD, these have been saved into the data directory and will persist even if you start again the container with other values.

If you want to use another user/password you can

- Change the user password ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/sql-alteruser.html) / [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12721095/2347196))
- Add a new user ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html))
- Remove all containers and linked volumes with the -v flag of `docker-compose down` ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_down/), YOU WILL LOSE ALL DATA IN THE VOLUMES!)

---

edit: [as atish.s pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77145869/2347196) you are also trying to connect to the database on the wrong port (the DB is exposed on 5433, based on the logs you pasted you are trying to connect to 57514)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was I only deleted the container and not the volumes. After deleting the volume and creating the container again. I am able to connect with my new credentials. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pointing to the wrong postgres instance. Your instance is running on the port `5433` but the error is referring to `port 57514 failed`.

I also gave the docker-compose file a quick try and it looks to be working as expected when using the connection details below.

[image: connection details]

Comment: One of the problems is that the port on the container is not the same as specified in the docker-compose.yml. In the docker I have the 57514  port. And if I connect to this port with the user app, db app and pasword !ChangeMe! as it is default setting in the docker-compose.yml it connects. Even if I have different user, db name and password in the container as in the picture. 

If I create the docker via comand line with docker run --name postgres-1 -e POSTGRES_USER=test -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123 -e POSTGRES_DB=testdb -p5433:5432 postgres:15 , I am able to connect to it with these credentials

Comment: The problem is only if I create it with docker-compose up -d based on the docker-compose.yml in my project folder.