# How to access django database from another application

Tags: python, django

I am maintaining one database in django and some another application written in java want to access that database and add some data in it. Here i want common database for Java application and Django application. So whenever need data, we can make query to that database directly. How is it possible???

Comment: What database backend are you using for Django? What is stopping you from just querying the same database in Java, in the appropriate language? What have you tried?

Comment: @Joost i m using sqlite3. I dont know java but my temate here want to update data in database....which data i need to tell him...how can i check my database ip and port??

Comment: See argaen's answer, below. That pretty much sums it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using sqlite3 you don't need to tell any ip or port to your teammate. He just needs the path/name of the sqlite database. You can find the name in your **settings.py** file in the 'DATABASE' variable.

Comment: Additionally, if the Java code is not running on the same machine, consider switching the Django backend to e.g. MySQL, so that you easily have an actual database server running.

Comment: @Joost yes java code is not running on same machine......is it necessary to switch to MySQL???

Comment: Well, there are sqlite3 server solutions, but the last painful road is probably to switch database backends in Django. It's well-documented and quite easy.

Comment: Yes, sqlite3 is only for local access. If you need to access the database from a remote machine, consider using Postgres or Mysql. Here you have a simple config example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394331/how-to-setup-postgresql-database-in-django

Comment: Plus sqlite3 is not a serious backend database for production. It should only be used for testing.