# Django Error while installing graphite

Tags: python, django, graphite

I am following [Graphite](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-graphite-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) tutorial to install graphite on my Ubuntu system, as soon as I try to run this command

```
$sudo graphite-manage syncdb
```

this exception is thrown

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 isnot an available database backend.Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:ubase, umysql, uoracle, usqlite3 Error was: No module named postgresql_psycopg2.base`

I did some search to find out the cause and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639327/error-was-no-module-named-postgresql-base) but its still persisting, can anybody help please

Comment: did you installed `postgres` using `pip install psycopg2`

Comment: yep just ran this command again and this msg popped : Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: try this command `sudo apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin`

Comment: same issue comming after running above command

Comment: please show your `database engine` string.

Comment: my complete db props

Comment: `DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'graphite',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': 'graphite',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}`

Comment: and I can access graphite user using `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U graphite`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141616/discussion-between-mahendra-kamble-and-sayim-khan).

Comment: What is the version of Python and Django you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling mistake in your `settings.py`, it should be

`'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'`

but in your file it is

`'ENGINE': 'Django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'`

Fix the typo and things will work.

Comment: no its correct, i just copied wrong error msg, property is like `        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
`

Comment: error msg: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    u'base', u'mysql', u'oracle', u'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named postgresql_psycopg2.base