# Using multiple columns as ForeignKey to return in another table

Tags: python, django, postgresql, object, django-models

I'm new to Django so I make 3 simple tables to return a WishList. The thing is that I want whenever user asks for WishList, his/her `user_id` is used to make a `SELECT` query to return his/her own WishList. And I want to get product title and product url from my WishList table. I'm using `to_field` but with that way I only can get product title back. I don't know much about Django so help me!

## Product

```
class Product(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('id', 'title'),)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True,
                             help_text='Name of the product')
    url = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='',
                           help_text='Url of the product')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Product: {}'.format(self.title)
```

## WishList

```
class WishList(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'product'),)

    user = models.ForeignKey(fbuser,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         help_text='Facebook user',
                         to_field='user_id')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, to_field='title', db_column='title',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'WishList: {}'.format(self.user)
```

Comment: Can you show us how are you trying to access product on wish list object?

Comment: `query = cur.execute("SELECT title FROM wishlist_wishlist WHERE user_id ='"+user_id+"'")` I use this query

Comment: Why are you using cursors? why not use django orm https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-all-objects?

Comment: Because I'm using postgresql as my database and psycopg2 works for me to get data so

Comment: So? Why don't you setup django DATABASES? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5421511/3627387

Comment: I did setup it in my `settings.py`, then I search how to get data from postgresql and I found `cursor` class, I tried and it works. Because i'm new and I didn't read the documentation clearly so when found a way that works and I thought it's oke to use.

Comment: Understood. You should only use `cursor` when you can't get desired sql in form of ORM. For your question it's pretty easy to do in ORM.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I didn't know much about Django and I should read the documentation earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good practice to override to_field to another field different than your model.pk unless you have a really good reason and you know what you are doing (definitely not the case right now).

So after you read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/), you will know that in order to get wishlisht related to a user, you can use the `ForeignKey` reverse relation to get all related wishlists for a user.

```
user_wishlists = my_user.wishlist_set.all()
#Because we know that you want to access the wishlist.products
#in order to optimize things (in terms of db queries)
#you can add and .select_related('product')
#e.g, user_wishlists = my_user.wishlist_set.all().select_related('product')

#now follow the wishlist.product foreign key to access the related product for every wishlist
for wishlist in user_wishlists:
    product = wishlist.product
    print (product.id, product.title, product.url)
```

Now after you read a little bit more of the documentation
you will notice that your `WishList` model is in fact an [intermediate model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) for a `ManyToMany` relation between `User` and his wished products, then you will know that you can define a M2M field between user and products via `WishList` like so:

```
class FbUser(models.Model):
    #...
    wished_products = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product,
        through='WishList',
        through_fields=('user', 'product')
    )

#and now accessing user wished products would be easy as:
user_wished_products = my_user.wished_products.all()
for product in user_wished_products:
    print (product.id, product.title, product.url)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'` I got this error, it causes because first parameter to `ManyToManyField` must be either a model, a model name or string. It's weird because `Product` is a model

Comment: I guess the `Product` class is defined in another application? Try to refer it with the application name too, e.g. `'myapp.Product'`.

Comment: Yes, all 3 tables are all made in different application. I tried to use `'myapp.Product'` but it doesn't work for me. What I did is just add a column `url` in my WishList model, then return it with the title also. It worked but I dont think that it's good code. So i'm still trying to better my code

Comment: Instead of writing it as a string `'myapp.Product'`, try to import the class (e.g. `from myapp.models import Product`), then send that to the M2M field definition: `models.ManyToManyField(Product, ....)` (no string used).