# DRF error - sqlite3.OperationalError: too many columns on new__budgets_budget

Tags: database, django-rest-framework

DRF error - sqlite3.OperationalError: too many columns on new__budgets_budget

I had a large table Budget maybe around 1000, I added about 700 more rows

and got the above error when migrating.

I went ahead and added another 1000  but I made 3 tables each around 1000 and got same error.

Thinking either there is a limit to tables or it's just got stuck in the past as its refering to Budget which no longer exists... now it's
Budget1
Budget2
Budget3

Same error

Comment: This is what was in terminal - return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: too many columns on new__budgets_budget

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you have three tables each with 1000 rows. but the error is related to column limit size which is quite high in SQLite( [by default 2000](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)) if your table consists of more than 2000 columns, i would suggest You probably want to rethink your design. Any non-data warehouse application is highly unlikely to need or be terribly efficient with thousands of columns.

and if you think that django has not migrated and is "stuck in the past" try to delete all your migrations and do makemigrations again ofcourse have a backup of your data before deleting. i suggest you also try to use another database like postgresql as sqlite has lots of limits that might cause errors.
check this link for using postgresql in django:
[How to set up a PostgreSQL database in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394331/how-to-set-up-a-postgresql-database-in-django)

Comment: Hi serohrt, Thanks for your answer. What I have done is like you said above made 3 new tables but it still gave the error so I made 3 new apps with one table in each. Didn't get the error when migrating but it just makes thing a bit tricker on the React side as I need 3 different. Submit functions in the Create and Edit pages. I already was using that for the Edit as I was using formdata which I found out only takes 1000. I was calling the 2nd from the end of the first and likewise for the 3rd and it worked despite a few online comments about this being now the correct way.